# Napa AddIn Taskpane Angular

Tags: javascript, ms-office, napa

Is it possible to use Angular in a Napa Office Addin Taskpane?

I have created a simple Office Addin Taskpane including Angular. When i run it locally, it works as expected, but when i run the same code online, the Angular bindings fail.
I have tried adding the angular.min.js file to the project and wrapping the data bound changes in '$scope.$apply(function() {...})' functions, but still no luck.

[screen shot](http://6377a4303138ef8eab20-ca4532d882fe562d6af8309397556964.r32.cf1.rackcdn.com/2015-06-05_14-16-22.jpg)

[Test Project](http://6377a4303138ef8eab20-ca4532d882fe562d6af8309397556964.r32.cf1.rackcdn.com/AngularAddin1.zip)

or is there a better way to do data binding in Napa?